# компиляторы для qt(и их настройка),windows sdk?,и c++

Tags: c++, windows, qt, компилятор, sdk

> Всего лишь скачать,и посмотреть документацию? Ничоси легко!

-Я в прошлом

---

Ага,со мной и моей огненной удачей о таком только мечтать можно...

Точнее с моей придирчивости.

Вот смотрите:

[image: Смотрите на предупреждения]

Мне не нравится эти воскл. знаки.
Погуглив,я нашёл информацию о том,что компиляторы для десктопа идут вместе с windows sdk.

Я скачал windows sdk (установщик) а он мне такой:у тебя уже есть windows sdk удали его.

установщик visual studio:

[image: ЧТО]

,

[image: ЧТО №2]

Не волнуйтесь,вы не одни,я тоже запутался.

Ну так вот,помогите всё наладить в qt(и visual studio) Пожалуйста!

Comment: Видимо у вас QT для VS2015, а установлено VS2017.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно установить отладчик CDB

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нет,не согласен.Там же написано: _Компилятор_  может не создавать код совместимый с профилем таким-то.

Comment: Если вы хотите собрать 32-разрядную программу, а не 64, то вам надо либо пользоваться VS2015, либо под VS2017 x86 собирать Qt самостоятельно